# Staying in Europe after Schengen visa expires

Tags: schengen

I am traveling to Amsterdam and then Dusseldorf and Brussels for about 20 days. My Schengen visa expires one week after the date of entry. Is this allowed, or should I apply for another Schengen visa?

Comment: What were your intended travel dates and purpose as stated in your visa application?

Comment: No, unlike many other visas (US, China etc) where visa expiration date  essentially means "enter before", Schengen visas are invalid after its expiration date, and by this date you must exit the Schengen area.